# How can I check Windows Server 2008 health status and use them with Python

Tags: windows, python, health, healthcheck

I am working on a project for which I need to create a Python class which can determine underlying OS on which it is running and performs a sequence of checks if OS is found to be Windows Server 2003/2008.

Currently my check includes following parameters:

1. CPU Utilization Check
2. RAM Utilization Check
3. HD Volume space available
4. Well configured network parameters like DNS and DHCP
5. RDP and other critical application services running

For 1 to 3 information can be extracted from *Windows Task Manager* BUT the question in **HOW ?**

For 4, *ipconfig /all* output would be fine and I think I would be able to extract them either from some python modules or regex ! (Believe me I am not sure)

For 5, I think I should use powershell trimmed *Get-Services* output.

I look foreward to seek help on points 1 to 3

1. How can I extract this information from windows machine ?
2. How can I use that information for further processing in Python ?

Apart from this any type of suggestion/query/improvements/known issues are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a look for parts 1, 2 and 3: http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

As for network parameters, you might have a bit better luck with parsing the output from the following command: `netsh interface ipv4 show config` for interface configuration and DNS.
However you can also try this: http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/
It doesn't give very friendly interface names on Windows but works. However I don't think it shows whether you're using DHCP or what you're using for DNS.

Lastly for 5 there is http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303339/ but it is unhelpfully only processes. There's a WMI Python module that can provide service information however: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html